# Cell does not automatically highlighted when doing multi-selection in editing mode for UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Why cells not highlighted when being selected in multi-section mode in edit mode for UITableView? Does the override of touch detection affected this part? I wanna know to to debug circumstances like this.

Comment: The circles with checkmarks appear to indicate which rows are selected (unless you've prevented editing).

Comment: Yeah. What I meant is that part didn't work. and I'm not preventing that from happening, because all the selecting-related callback functions works just fine, like didselect and diddeselect.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you set the editing property of a UITableView to be true, its cells stop being tappable. To make it tappable, you can use following code to enable selection in editing mode

```
tableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = true

tableView. allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = true
```

Comment: actually I'm trying to do multi-selections, instead of doing single selection while editing. So i tried: ```tableView.allowMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = true```. I can multi-select functionally by telling from the number of indexPathesSelected, but the cell itself is not highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

You need the following to be the case:

- the table's `allowsSelectionDuringEditing` and `allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing` must *both* be `true`
- you must return `true` from both `tableView(_:canEditRowAt:)` and `tableView(_:willSelectRowAt:)`
- the cell's `multipleSelectionBackgroundView` is not `nil` if you want to see the background do something to indicate selection
- new in iOS 13 you can detect multiple selection with `tableViewDidEndMultipleSelectionInteraction(_:)`